# Proof of property of Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R} $ with non-zero measure

Tags: measure-theory

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to prove the following:
Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(A)>0$. Then $\forall \epsilon \in (0,1)\ \exists$ an open interval $I$ such that $m(A\cap I)>\epsilon m(I)$. This makes sense to me, especially if A is a connected subset of the reals but I've got no clue how to prove it in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any $\epsilon$ such that the statement is false, note that $m(A\cap I) \le \epsilon m(I)$ implies that for any $\delta \in (\epsilon, 1)$, there is a covering of $A\cap I$ by a sequence of disjoint open intervals of total measure less than $\delta m(I)$.  Do this for all $I$ in a sequence of disjoint open intervals covering $A$ such that their total measure is less than $(1/\delta)m(A)$, and you will have a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful (=